# Identifying correct day based on tithi

Tags: astrology

Hindu calendar is bit complex than English calendar. For Hindu calendar,time and day do not work like modern English calendar. For example; coming Purnima tithi will start from 11th August, 10:59 a.m. which will end next day i.e. 12th August 7:05 a.m. Since people celebrate raksha bandhan this purnima, it is confusing to celebrate *when* as it falls both days. This is just an example, there are many cases as such when a single day festival falls on two days. What do shastras say about it? Should Hindus celebrate on both day or just one day? If one day then which day is to select?

Comment: Sunrise is the time where a day begins. There is your answer

Comment: As per Hindu calender day starts at sunrise(of that day), unlike an english calendar that begins at 12AM... Sunrise to sunset aka -ahas, followed by  Nisha/ratra - sunset to sunrise.  Thus known as Ahoratra/Aharnisha. 
Ahas/Nisha is further subdivided into divisions of time(like muhurt). The day in which Tithi/nakshtra is present in (a division of time like) muhurt ,takes precedence over the other day.This is just a rough idea.

Comment: @AgamasTantras I am aware of that, just looking for validation from authentic sources.

Comment: @Athrey Yes aware of that.

Comment: Although Tithi at Sunrise is given importance for some festivals, some festivals are decided based on times of exact events, like Rama Navami must be day when Navami tithi present at Noon time (Birth of Rama) irrespective of Sunrise Tithi and Krishna Ashtami when Ashtami tithi at midnight and, Mahashivaratri when Chaturdashi tithi at midnight/Nishita Kala.